# In Qiskit, add amplitude_damping_error to qubits in the circuit, how to know T1?

Tags: qiskit

In Qiskit, add amplitude_damping_error to qubits in the circuit, how to know T1?

`amplitude_damping_error(param_amp, excited_state_population=0, canonical_kraus=True)`

What is the process of add amplitude_damping_error to a instruction of one qubit?
What is the meaning of param_amp?
How can I compute the T1 from param_amp or other parameters are needed?

Answer (score 3):

**Amplitude Damping Channel**

When describing a quantum system undergoing energy dissipation because of some type of interaction with the environment, we apply a quantum operation known as amplitude damping. So, amplitude damping describes a decay process; a channel where the state $|0\rangle$ is transmitted faithfully but $|1\rangle$ (the excited state) is transmitted correctly with probability $1-\gamma$ and decays to $|0\rangle$ (the ground state) with probability $\gamma$ **<sup>[1]</sup>**.

The parameter $\gamma$ is a time-dependent function, which is often characterized by $1- e^{-t/T_1}$, where $t$ is time and $T_1$ is the *relaxation time*.

---

**Using `amplitude_damping_error()`**

In Qiskit you add amplitude damping error to a one-qubit instruction as follows:

```
from qiskit_aer.noise import NoiseModel
from qiskit_aer.noise.errors.standard_errors import amplitude_damping_error
import numpy as np

# 1) Calculate param_amp (i.e., gamma)
T1 = 25.0
gate_time = 0.1
param_amp = 1 - np.exp(-gate_time / T1)

# 2) Define amplitude damping quantum error channel
error = amplitude_damping_error(param_amp)

# 3) Create the noise model and add the quantum error to it:
noise_model = NoiseModel()
noise_model.add_all_qubit_quantum_error(error, ['u'])
# Or,
#noise_model.add_quantum_error(error, 'u', [0])

# 4) Pass the noise model to the simulator:
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator
backend = AerSimulator(noise_model = noise_model)
job = backend.run(circuit)
```

---

[1] [Quantum Computing Explained - McMahon](https://doi.org/10.1002/9780470181386)

Answer (score 0):

`param_amp` is the damping parameter for the amplitude damping channel.

The Kraus operators used to define this channel are available in their matrix form on [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplitude_damping_channel). The same channel is also defined in the [Qiskit documentation](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit_aer.noise.amplitude_damping_error.html).

Here's [an example in Qiskit documentation for adding damping error](https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/simulators/5_noise_transformation.html#Example:-Approximating-amplitude-damping-noise-with-reset-noise.) and [here's another example for finding T1](https://qiskit.org/documentation/experiments/tutorials/t1.html). In order to be able to do what you want, you will have to change the noise model in the latter example.